# Select All records of a class with LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, ado.net-entity-data-model

I am trying get some records from a linq query

```
dataentities db = new dataentities();
db.Tabel1.Select(x=> new lcclsAccDueList {LedgerName ,LedgerId,Amount ,AmountInString ,Expr2,Name ,StopID ,VIP  }).ToList();
```

I made this class

```
 public class lcclsAccDueList
    {
        public string LedgerName { get; set; }
        public decimal LedgerId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Amount { get; set; }
        public string AmountInString { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Expr2 { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> StopID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> VIP { get; set; }
    }
```

Is there any other way to select all records like

```
dataentities db = new dataentities();
db.Tabel1.Select(x=> new lcclsAccDueList { * }).ToList();
// * indicates select all records
```

Comment: Provide more detail. do you want to get data from table1?

Comment: yes i want to get all data from table1 .. and tabel1 is of same properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create `lcclsAccDueList` class constructor which takes `source` and maps all the properties:

```
public class lcclsAccDueList
{
    public lcclsAccDueList() {}
    public lcclsAccDueList(tableItem source)
    {
        LedgerName = source.LedgerName;
        LedgerId = source.LedgerId;
        // (...)
    }

    public string LedgerName { get; set; }
    public decimal LedgerId { get; set; }
    // (...)
}
```

And then use it within your query:

```
dataentities db = new dataentities();
db.Tabel1.Select(x => new lcclsAccDueList(x)).ToList();
```

Or you can use auto mapping libraries, like [automapper](http://automapper.org/):

Create map:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<tableItem, lcclsAccDueList>();
```

And then use it within you query:

```
dataentities db = new dataentities();
db.Tabel1.Select(x => Mapper.Map<lcclsAccDueList>(x);).ToList();
```